# Power Bi recalculate status of the store depending on Date Slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, datamodel, slicers

Please check the screenshots first:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

I am having difficulty recalculating store status based on first date they had order depending on date slicer selection. To keep things simple I have: `date` table, `store` table and `order data` table. This task is tricky since I have 2 dimensional tables and 1 fact table and already have a `date` table connected to my `order date` on my fact table.

But now I need categorize my stores into new and old and the] kicker that it has to be dynamic:

[image]

For a selected period of time per slicer, the goal is to see new stores that had their first order date in the given period of year from slicer selection time.

ex: date selected was 04/2021 then I need to see all new stores which would have their first order date b/n 04/2020 and 04/2021 and stores that has order date prior to 04/2020 are no longer new, but old. If I bring a separate fact table with that calculation and make relationship b/n date table, I will not be able to connect to my `order date` fact table, which I need to.

Answer (score 0):

A measure should be created to get the store's first order date using an **ALL** filter.

`First Order Date = CALCULATE(MIN(Fact_Orders[OrderDate]), ALL('Date'))`

So this measure can be used to classify the stores.

```
Store Classification = 
        
IF 
    (
    [First Order Date] >= DATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date].[Year]) - 1, SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date].[MonthNo]), 1) && 
            [First Order Date] < DATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date].[Year]), SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date].[MonthNo]) + 1, 1), 
    "NEW", 
    BLANK()
    )
```

This formula works only if one value is selected in a slicer as it uses **SELECTEDVALUE**. Instead you can also use `MIN('Date'[Date])` and `MAX('Date'[Date])`.

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer.  However, I was not clear with my problem. I need to use tat calculated classification as a slicer so I can see for ex, new stores vs old stores performance.  Once we do dax, we cant put that into slicer.